# Django tables2 not rendering properly

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm following the example on https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#querysets

The example shown at above site doesn't work properly for me. Please see my code below. The table is displayed but not rendered properly. Instead of using PersonsTable(), if I use the objects collection, table is rendered properly.

The PersonsTable() is from the above page, as is.

I'd like to be able to use PersonsTable()'s fields to filter displayed columns and get the nice formatting from django-tables2...

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
def person_list(request):
    #table = PersonsTable(Person.objects.all())  # this is from example, table is rendered plainly w/o any formatting present or up/down arrows
    table = Person.objects.all()                 # rendering works

    return render(request, 'person_list.html', {'table': table})
```

Template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    {% render_table table %}
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your template code?

Comment: Updated post w/my template code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After modifying my PersonsTable class to include 'attr...', table now renders.

```
class PersonsTable(django_tables2.Table):

    class Meta: 
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}   # this fixed table rendering
        model = Person
```